# List all entries from particular channel when being already in that channel entry

Tags: channel-entries

Well, I have suspected that code below will list all entries from channel `creators`

```
<ul>
{exp:channel:entries channel="creators" orderby="title" sort="asc"}
<li><a href="{site_url}{segment_1}/{url_title}">{title}</a></li>
{/exp:channel:entries}
</ul>
```

but when I'm in any entry from that channel it displays only that particular entry not all from that channel.

So what is my problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the dynamic="no" parameter. http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/channel_entries.html#dynamic

Comment: Thanks. Adding `dynamic="no"` works. Also requires change `{segment_1}` to channel name itself to get this working properly.